# How to calculate conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

How can I calculate a conditional expectation like below?

$E(X^3 - Y^3 | X-Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(X^3 - Y^3 | X-Y)= E(X^3 | X - Y) - E(Y^3 | X - Y)$$

You never said if the variable was discrete or continuous. I'm going to do the discrete case below.

$$=\sum(X^3 \times \textrm{Pr}(X^3|X-Y)) - \sum(Y^3 \times \textrm{Pr}(Y^3|X-Y)) $$

For the continuous case, you integrate where there's a summation, and use the PDF for the conditional probability.

Comment: Thank you.I meant the continuous but it also will be useful for discrete mod.